# Different approach to call a mutable method inside a for iterator

Tags: rust

I'm trying to call a mutable method inside a immutable scope with gives me: `error[E0502]`.

I'm already understand why this error occurs but I'm struggle on how to fix it or how to do a different approach that works.

Here a MCVE

```
 struct A {
    list: Vec<i8>,
    has_three: bool,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            list: vec![1,2,3],
            has_three: false,
        }
    }
    pub fn mutable_method(&mut self) {
        for item in self.list.iter() {
            self.mutable_method2(item);
        }
    }
    
    fn mutable_method2(&mut self, item: &i8) {
        let b: i8 = 3;
        if item == &b {
            self.has_three = true;
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    a.mutable_method();
}
```

And the Error received:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
14 |         for item in self.list.iter() {
   |                     ----------------
   |                     |
   |                     immutable borrow occurs here
   |                     immutable borrow later used here
15 |             self.mutable_method2(item);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for another approach. If I correctly assume that your goal is to have `has_three` be true if any entry is 3, that's much more easily done this way:

```rust
pub fn mutable_method(&mut self) {
    self.has_three = self.list.iter().any(|&x| x == 3);
}
```

By the way, you need to make sure `mutable_method` is actually called appropriately, otherwise you will end up in logically invalid states. That's not good practice. Consider extracting this to the constructing function already.

**Some background**

The underlying problem is that your initial approach wants to borrow `self` mutably, while already borrowing it immutably. However, logically, your code is not obviously invalid, as you only borrow a part of the struct mutably that you do not also borrow immutably. This information is lost though.

We make the safety explicit by factoring into two implicit operations,

```rust
let tmp = self.list.iter().any(|&x| x == 3);
self.has_three = tmp;
```

which both operate on the struct in a 'clear fashion', either mutably or immutably. That is how you can approach such problems.